# X BadRequest error when running a SDL2 program over SSH, but not with valgrind?

Tags: ssh, x11

I'm relatively new to SDL2, but I made a quick and dirty program for something. It works fine on my laptop, but when I connect to my server, and try to test it using X tunneling over SSH, I get the outline of a window for a split second, then I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Serial number of failed request:  202
  Current serial number in output stream:  203
```

Other X programs work fine though? Even other SDL2 programs, too.

Looking online, I get results about it being OpenGL problems, but my program doesn't use OpenGL at all. Or, at least, it shouldn't, as my *other* SDL2 programs work fine, and this doesn't really use anything too complicated, just surfaces and bitplanes. Anyway, I tried the solutions and alas, nothing worked...

Interestingly, when I run it through valgrind, I get this, and *not* the above error:

```
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1025 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1026 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1027 in syscall close()
==29836==    Use --log-fd=<number> to select an alternative log fd.
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1028 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1029 in syscall close()
```

followed by a heap summary, as if the program stopped, but it continues running... and after a while, the program begins to run? And when I close out of it, it shows *another* heap summary...

​

Here's the full log, in case it's helpful at all.

```
kit@KitServ:~/git/video-compress$ ./a.out a.vid
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Serial number of failed request:  202
  Current serial number in output stream:  203
kit@KitServ:~/git/video-compress$ valgrind ./a.out a.vid
==29814== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29814== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29814== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29814== Command: ./a.out a.vid
==29814== 
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1025 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1026 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1027 in syscall close()
==29836==    Use --log-fd=<number> to select an alternative log fd.
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1028 in syscall close()
==29836== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1029 in syscall close()
==29836== 
==29836== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29836==     in use at exit: 12,828,426 bytes in 56,137 blocks
==29836==   total heap usage: 119,755 allocs, 63,618 frees, 53,804,810 bytes allocated
==29836== 
==29836== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29836==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29836==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29836==      possibly lost: 728 bytes in 18 blocks
==29836==    still reachable: 12,827,698 bytes in 56,119 blocks
==29836==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==29836==                         newarray           : 832 bytes in 16 blocks
==29836==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29836== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==29836== 
==29836== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==29836== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
^C==29814== 
==29814== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29814==     in use at exit: 10,225,041 bytes in 7,548 blocks
==29814==   total heap usage: 156,304 allocs, 148,756 frees, 124,528,896 bytes allocated
==29814== 
==29814== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29814==    definitely lost: 1,168 bytes in 15 blocks
==29814==    indirectly lost: 171,414 bytes in 776 blocks
==29814==      possibly lost: 218,440 bytes in 503 blocks
==29814==    still reachable: 9,834,019 bytes in 6,254 blocks
==29814==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==29814==                         newarray           : 832 bytes in 16 blocks
==29814==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29814== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==29814== 
==29814== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==29814== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
kit@KitServ:~/git/video-compress$
```

In case it's helpful at all, [here's the program in question](https://github.com/aouwt/video-compress).